# Why is this episode titled "Book of the Stranger"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, title

In *Game of Thrones*, episode 54 of series 6 has been given title *Book of the Stranger*. How is this title relevant to the episode? What have I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [GoT Wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_the_Stranger#Notes):

> The Stranger is the aspect of The Seven that represents death. The
>   holy text of the Faith of the Seven is The Seven-Pointed Star, which
>   is divided up into internal books (like the real-life Christian Bible,
>   etc.) - i.e., one internal division is the "Book of the Maiden"
>   (devoted to The Maiden, another aspect of the Seven). The episode
>   takes its name from when Margaery points out that the High Septon is
>   quoting a verse from the Book of the Stranger.

Below is the abovementioned [dialogue](http://gameofthronesfanon.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_the_Stranger_(Fanon)/Transcript):

> HIGH SPARROW: Of course, but for you, that means seeking out money,
>   finery, power. Seeking out your family means seeking out sin. I’m not
>   maligning you. I sought those things out, too. To the exclusion of all
>   else. My father was a cobbler. He died with I was young and I took
>   over his shop. He was a simple man and he made simple shoes. But I
>   found that the more work I put into my shoes, the more people wanted
>   them. Fine leather, ornamentation, detailing, and time. Time most of
>   all. Dozens of hours spent on a single pair.
>
> MARGAERY: Quality takes time.
>
> HIGH SPARROW: Yes. I imagine you’ve worn a year of someone’s life on
>   your back. The highborn liked to cover their feet with my time and
>   they paid well for the privilege. I used their money to buy a taste of
>   their lives for myself. Each time I indulged, I felt myself ascending
>   to something better.
>
> MARGAERY: And one day you walked through a graveyard and realized it
>   was all for nothing and set out on the path to righteousness. Book of
>   the Stranger, verse 25.

Note that often GoT episode titles match several events/characters. In this case a possible interpretation is that the title is also a reference to Daenerys who in this episode is a stranger that brings death to the Dothraki khals.

Comment: What was Arya up to in this episode? Another little detail, explicit in the books and I think hinted at in passing in the show, is that "The Stranger" -  the most sinister and least popular of the 7 due to association with danger, death and the unknown - is one of "the many faces" of the Many Faced God the faceless assassins worship, which are essentially every culture's own take on death.

Comment: Oh, she doesn't appear this episode. There goes that theory... :-) still, maybe someone will enjoy the trivia...

Comment: Haha. Why would I not missed that when it is conversation with septon,  most boring and dragging